# Spring Boot JPA Transaction during Test - not throwing key violation exception on insert

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have the following test that generates an invitation with a company id and an email.  Then, we generate a second with the same company id and email.  This should violate the unique constraint on the DB (See the Invitation entity).  Thing is, the test passes as listed below (the transaction is never committed for the second insert, I guess)

If I do a `findAll()` after the second insert (see the comment below) I get an exception on the line where the `findAll()` is that the index violation has occurred.

How do I make the methods in the `UserService` commit their transactions when the method returns, so the test code will throw an exception as-is?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class UserServiceTest {
    ... Everything is autowired
    @Test
    public void testCreateInvitation() {
        String email = "test2@example.com";
        Company company = userService.createCompany("ACMETEST", tu);

        assertTrue(invitationRepository.count() == 0l);
        assertNotNull(userService.sendInvitation(company, email));
        assertTrue(invitationRepository.count() == 1l);

        assertTrue(invitationRepository.findAllByEmail(email).size() == 1);
        // Second should throw exception
        userService.sendInvitation(company, email);

        // If this line is uncommented, I get key violation exception, otherwise, test passes!!!!????
        //Iterable<Invitation> all = invitationRepository.findAll();
    }
```

Invitation class and constraint:

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"email", "company_id"}))
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator= ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
@Data
public class Invitation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    String id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="company_id")
    private Company company;

    String email;

    Date inviteDate;

    Date registerDate;
}
```

User Service:

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class UserService {
    public Invitation sendInvitation(Company company, String toEmail) {
        Invitation invitation = new Invitation();
        invitation.setCompany(company);
        invitation.setInviteDate(new Date());
        invitation.setEmail(toEmail);
        try {
            // TODO send email
            return invitationRepository.save(invitation);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Cannot send invitation: {}", e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which database are you using in your tests?

Comment: h2, the spring boot default

Comment: Double check that constrains are actually made on the database.

Comment: It does, see the part about throwing the exception for the unique constraint violation if i uncomment the query below...

Comment: Get the same issue I think -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52697057/datajpatest-doest-work-with-genericgenerator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I make the methods in the UserService commit their transactions when the method returns, so the test code will throw an exception as-is?

Since `@DataJpaTest` is `@Transactional` itself. Code written in `@Test` method is executed within a transaction. You can change it using [Propogation.NOT_SUPPORTED](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#NOT_SUPPORTED) which

> Execute non-transactionally, suspend the current transaction if one exists

```
@Test
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public void testCreateInvitation() {
    // your test method body unchanged
}
```

Using this you should get an exception on the second `userService.sendInvitation(company, email);` call.

Also there are some other options.

Option 1:

Add `@Commit` to your test method.

All tests marked with `@Transactional` are [rolled back](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-tx-enabling-transactions) after its execution. But there is a subtle thing with Hibernate: it may delay executing sql until you commit a transaction (or call `flush` explicitly (option 2)).

Since a transaction rollbacked no insertions performed hence there is no constraint violation.

Beware that using `@Commit` you will get an exception thrown **outside** of your test method.

Option 2:

Use manual `flush()`:

If your repository `extends JpaRepository<>`:

```
@Test
public void testCreateInvitation() {
    // create first invitation,
    // create second invitation
    invitationRepository.flush();
}
```

Else inject `EntityManager` and call `flush()` on it:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Test
public void testCreateInvitation() {
    // create first invitation,
    // create second invitation
    em.flush();
}
```

You will get an exception when `invitationRepository.flush()` or `em.flush()` called.

Option 3:
Use GenerationType.IDENTITY:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

Hibernate must assign id to an `@Entity` after you `save()` it. But it has no way of getting an id for an entity without executing an `insert`.

**P.S.**
There is a one thing confusing me.

You use `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` and it should force commiting a transaction after the method is executed. Please check your logs to see if transactions are actually working.

Comment: This is correct, specifically `Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED`  Thanks.  Couple other comments: 1 - `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` does not work, maybe because it's the *only* transaction?  2 - I have no `flush()` method in the repository.  3 - I did not try the `IDENTITY` change because it's working.

Comment: @mikeb 1 - No. Any call to your service method should be executed within a new transaction regardless of any transactions started outside. I suggest you to share a minimal version of your project where the issue is observable so we can figure out why this exactly happening. 2 - I edited my answer, see option 2

Comment: @mikeb Or... Do you instantiate UserService by yourself?